# Linking a shared library using gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have a shared library (*.so) created using Real View Compiler Tools (RVCT 3.2) on windows target. Then I try to link this *.so file with my application using gcc on linux system.

What is the gcc option to link this shared library with my application linux?

My question is, is the `-shared` option, which is used as

```
gcc -shared myfile.so
```

..., used to create the SO file or to link the SO file? I believe it creates something like:

```
gcc -lmyfile.so
```

Is this enough? Or is there any other switch to tell the linker that it's a dynamic library (shared object)?

Answer (score 69):

What worked for me was:

```
gcc -L. -l:myfile.so
```

Comment: -L{path to file containing library} -l${library name}
 if I have a library named libmine.so in /home/newhall/lib/ then I'd do the following to link it into my program:
$gcc -o myprog myprog.c  -L/home/newhall/lib -lmine
[Reference Site](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html)

Comment: For those wondering about the colon, it gets the linker to look for a file with the exact name specified, instead of looking for variations on the name. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48540643/1175455.

Comment: Is there any difference between a dynamic library (.so) and a static library (.a) while linking ? I always thought that dynamic libraries were only used at run time and not a compilation time. Did I miss something ?

Comment: This says "undefined reference" but it is defined in the file. Why?

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/

Comment: Don't forget export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so it points to the curr dirr

Answer (score 29):

`gcc -lmyfile` should be enough (provided that your library is named `libmyfile.so`). The linker searches for shared objects when possible and AFAIK prefers them.

Comment: I have a related question: In case my library libmyfile.so is a symlink to libyourfile.so, will linking my program using gcc -lmyfile still work? (I need to maintain backward compatibility of certain clients which are are unaware of the library name change.)

Comment: @jpalecek Does it work if the file name has the extension .dll?

Comment: What if the library not in `/usr/bin/ld`?

Comment: Add option `-L/path/to/so/folder/` to add search folder for `.so`

Comment: I tried to link `libraryName.dll` in Eclipse CDT, however it couldn't link when I specified full file name - it only works when specified filename WITHOUT extension: `libraryName`. So the linker option is `-llibraryName`.

Comment: what if we have 2 different versions of myfile lib and want to attach only one of them? How do we do that?