# gcc library option with a colon, -l:libevent.a

Tags: gcc, static-libraries

I'm going through a Makefile. Found this interesting bit of code, `LIBS = -l:libevent.a`. Was digging through gcc documentation but didn't find anything relevant. Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It instructs the linker to find and link a library with the exact name `libevent.a`,
in the specified (`-Ldir`) or default linker search directories, as opposed to
the usual convention whereby `-lfoo` instructs the linker to find and link either `libfoo.so` (shared library)
or `libfoo.a` (static library), preferring `libfoo.so` if both are found in the same search directory.

See the documentation of `-lnamespec | --library=namespec` in [the linker manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/ld/Options.html)