# Static linking with CGO does not find C function

Tags: c, go, cgo

I have a `libRA_CRC.a` where `nm -g REDALERT/libRA_CRC.a` gives me:

```
CRC.CPP.o:
0000000000000000 W _Z6__rotlIjET_S0_j
0000000000000000 T _ZN9CRCEngineclEc
000000000000006a T _ZN9CRCEngineclEPKvi
0000000000000000 W _ZNK9CRCEngine17Buffer_Needs_DataEv
0000000000000000 W _ZNK9CRCEngine5ValueEv

INIT_CRC.CPP.o:
0000000000000000 T Calculate_CRC
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U __stack_chk_fail
0000000000000000 W _ZN9CRCEngineC1Ei
0000000000000000 W _ZN9CRCEngineC2Ei
                 U _ZN9CRCEngineclEPKvi
```

Now I try to link this with a .go file where I reference:

```golang
  v := C.Calculate_CRC()
```

When compiling go via `go build -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags -static -l/build/libRA_CRC.a"` I get the error:

```
/tmp/go-build018540810/b047/_x002.o: In function `_cgo_636f3ffa0edd_Cfunc_Calculate_CRC':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:54: undefined reference to `Calculate_CRC'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Since there is a `Calculate_CRC` in .a I assume something around linking is going wrong.

Anyone any idea how to do this correctly?

Comment: The path to the static library `/build/libRA_CRC.a` looks odd, is that correct? You can check the commands with `-x`, but I'm not sure if the `-l` you're passing is making it to the correct linker invocation. Try setting `CGO_LDFLAGS` or using `#cgo LDFLAGS:` in the source.

Comment: Try replacing `-l/build/libRA_CRC.a` with `-L/build -l:libRA_CRC.a`. -L defines the library path, and -l: with a colon points to the exact file name. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532868/gcc-library-option-with-a-colon-llibevent-a). You may still need to set all this in CGO_LDFLAGS environment variable as JimB suggests.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? I am experiencing a similar problem trying to build https://github.com/system-pclub/GCatch