# Cannot compile C file using own library

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker-errors, ld

I'm trying to compile a `main.c` file using a library called `libft_malloc.so` that I've already created and put it in the same directory as the file, but it generates an error saying library not found.

Compilation goes like this:

```
$> gcc main.c -L. -lft_malloc.so -Iinclude
ld: library not found for -lft_malloc.so
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using an macOS.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26713370/898348

Comment: Use `-lft_malloc`.  No "`.so`" in the command-line option.  Alternatively, drop the `-L` and `-l` options altogether, and replace them with a path to the library file (`./libft_malloc.so`).

Comment: Do note, however, that it may be an issue to link against an uninstalled shared library, because the program will need to find it at runtime, too.  There are ways to provide for that, but it does not look like you are using any of them.

Comment: Yeah true, I have them both in the same directory.

Comment: I just love that macOS has `gcc` which is just an alias for `clang` :')